# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - Node Express Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

Code newbie here!

I'm following this guide to set up a backend server using Node.js, Express and MongoDB - https://www.codementor.io/@olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd

I keep receiving the following error in the terminal when using Postman.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I looked into the fact I may need to add a return statement somewhere, but since I've been following the guide, I shouldn't be having this issue?

Here's my controllers file where I think the problem may be:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');

exports.listAllTasks = function (req, res) {
  Task.find({}, function (err, task) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};

exports.createATask = function (req, res) {
  var newTask = new Task(req.body);
  newTask.save(function (err, task) {
    if (err);
    res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};

exports.readATask = function (req, res) {
  Task.findById(req.params.taskId, function (err, task) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};

exports.updateATask = function (req, res) {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.taskId },
    req.body,
    { new: true },
    function (err, task) {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      res.json(task);
    }
  );
};

exports.deleteATask = function (req, res) {
  Task.deleteMany(
    {
      _id: req.params.taskId,
    },
    function (err, task) {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      res.json({ message: 'Task successfully deleted' });
    }
  );
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` in your error handlers (`if (err)`). Otherwise after the error occurs and `res.send(err)` sends the response, execution just continues on the line after the `if` block and it tries to send the request again with `res.json()`.

Change

```
if (err) res.end(err)
```

to

```
if (err) return res.send(err)
```

or to

```
if (err) {
  res.send(err);
  return;
}
```

Either one is okay here as the return value of the callback isn't used for anything.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993786/error-err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-cli#comment116680272_65993786) comment suggests, whenever you are trying to send a different response based on a certain condition, you must *exit* the controller after sending the response.

Just change all your

`if(condition) res.end()`

to

`if(condition) return res.end() // notice the "return" keyword here`